# Determining the exact form of a projection in a Hilbert space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $$\Omega = \left\{f(x) \in \mathcal{L}^2[0,T]: \frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf(x)dx = \mu,~ a \le f(x) \le b,~\forall x \in [0,T]\right\},$$
where $\mathcal{L}^2[0,T]$ is the set of Lebesgue square-integrable functions on $[0,T]$ and $0 \le a \le \mu \le b$ are real numbers. Let $P_\tau(\Omega)$ denote the projection of $\Omega$ onto the space of $\mathcal{L}^2[0,\tau]$ functions for $\tau < T$; i.e., if $g \in P_\tau(\Omega)$ then there exists another function $\tilde{g}$ defined on $(\tau,T]$ where 
$$\hat{g}(t) = 
\begin{cases}
g(t),&t\in [0,\tau] \\
\tilde{g}(t), & t \in (\tau,T]
\end{cases}
\qquad \textrm{and}\qquad
\hat{g} \in \Omega.
$$

My question: If $h(t) \ge 0$ is defined on $[0,\tau]$ and $h \not \in P_\tau(\Omega)$, then I want to solve:
$$f^* = 
\begin{array}{rl}
\arg \min & \|f - h\| \\
\textrm{s.t.} & f \in P_\tau(\Omega),
\end{array}
$$
where $\langle f,h\rangle = \int_0^\tau f(t)h(t)dt$ is an inner product with induced norm $\|f\| = \sqrt{\langle f,f \rangle}$.

I am pretty sure $f^*$ exists and is unique, but I would really like to characterize it as much as possible as a function of $h$.

Progress thus far: If $\tau/T$ is small enough, then for $x \in [0,\tau]$, (1) if $h(x) > b$, then $f(x) = b$, (2) if $h(x) < a$, then $f(x)=a$, and (3) otherwise $f(x)=h(x)$. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how $\mu$ comes into play when $\tau/T$ is larger.

Comment: You can either just take $f=h$, or you can't because $(1/\tau)\int h$ is too far from $\mu$, and then you essentially have a constraint of the form $\int f=c$.

Comment: Even if $(1/\tau)\int h$ is close to $\mu$, I might not be able to take $f=h$ if $h$ violates the bounds $a$ and $b$. Also, replacing $a$ with $\mu$ in your original suggestion gives the constraint $\int_0^\tau f = \mu$; if $\tau = 1 < T$, $a > 0$, then this $f$ is not in the projection of $\Omega$.

Comment: I did leave out some details. If $(1/\tau)\int h$ is close enough to $\mu$ to not prevent me from taking $f=h$, I of course set $f=b$ where $h>b$ etc.

Comment: When the dust settles, the situation will be that I can either make the obvious choice for $f$, or I have to operate under a constraint of the form $\int f = c$.

Comment: The dust is still clouding my vision. But you've given me food for thought - thanks!